# Scrolling in table

Tags: jquery, scroll, html-table

I try this grid please check link [link reference](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx).

Now I successfully display this but there is no scroll.
Check image :

[image]

I use table for display data like this:

```
<table id="tabledata" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">

</table>
```

and i add these two classes like this in jquery

```
$("#tabledata tr:first").addClass('GridviewScrollHeader');
$("#tabledata tr").addClass('GridviewScrollItem');
```

i also add this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     gridviewScroll();
 });
 function gridviewScroll() {
     $('#tabledata').gridviewScroll({
         width: 660,
         height: 200
     });
 }
```

So how I add:

```
GridviewScrollPager
```

Comment: You can add the CSS property : `overflow:scroll;` on your `#tabledata`

Comment: Fix the height of the table, that will automatically gives you the scroll.

Comment: @Servuc in jquery like this  $("#tabledata tbody").addClass('scroll_me');?

Comment: @Manjuboyz.. as per your succestions it scroll everything including headers also.

Comment: That you have to handle, on their selector class.

Comment: @SUPER_USER just in CSS, but in think that `Manjubyz` has propably reason too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="300">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300">
            <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Class</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="width:320px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300">
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: You fixed the issue ?

Comment: yes .. but check this fiddle please. https://jsfiddle.net/2oc7gxov/ table formatting is wrong

Comment: Ok I can see the fiddle, let me know what you need in that fiddle ?

Comment: there is are two columns in table and look like table not in correct format and also scroll . check this image   http://i.imgur.com/ulWheqv.png   .. so when i add more columns then also scroll must set according to table

Comment: I didn't find any difference in the image and I am not understanding the context, could you show the image of adding multiple column and show me where the alignment is missing ?

Comment: i want to say i want scroll beside class column

Comment: Have added the code you asked for, if that is what you need then please accept  & upvote this as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<table id="tabledata" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="scroll_me">
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

<style>
.scroll_me
{
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll
}
</style>
```

Comment: in jquery like this ?  $("#tabledata tbody").addClass('scroll_me');

Comment: yes its like this.... I have provided you only idea... you have to work more based op your requirement.

Comment: you need to give more efforts by changing in class property.